# About pushforward of a sheaf of divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal variety over an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic, $f:X'\to X$ a log resolution, $L$ a Cartier divisor on $X$, and suppose $L\sim_{\mathbb{Q},f}E$, where $E$ is an effective $f$-exeptional divisor. Under the condition that
$$ f_*\mathcal{O}_{X'}(-L)=\mathcal{O}_{X'}(-f_*L),$$
(which is equivalent to $f_*\mathcal{O}_{X'}(-L)$ is a reflexive sheaf on $X$), can we prove $\left\lfloor E \right\rfloor=0$?

Indeed, the converse that if $\left\lfloor E \right\rfloor=0$, then $ f_*\mathcal{O}_{X'}(-L)=\mathcal{O}_{X'}(-f_*L)$ is Lemma 7.30 in [Kol13], and if we assume $L\sim_f E$, then the assertion is trivial. How to prove the assertion if we only assume $\mathbb{Q}$-linear equivalence, not just linear equivalence?

I believe there is a proof of that in [Fuj85], but it is unpublished, and I am unable to read this paper.

[Fuj85]: T. Fujita, “A relative version of Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing theorem”, unpublished manuscript, Univ. of Tokyo.

[Kol13]: J. Kollár, "Singularities of the minimal model program", Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics,
vol. 200, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, (2013)